# Enumerable foreach extend

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I created an extension to Enumerable to execute action fastly, so I have listed and in this method, I loop and if object executing the method in certain time out I return,
now I want to make the output generic because the method output will differ, any advice on what to do

this IEnumerable of processes, it's like load balancing, if the first not responded the second should, I want to return the output of the input Action

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action action, int timeOut)
    {            
        foreach (T element in source)
        {
            lock (source)
            {
                // Loop for all connections and get the fastest responsive proxy 
                foreach (var mxAccessProxy in source)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // check for the health 
                        Task executionTask = Task.Run(action);
                        if (executionTask.Wait(timeOut))
                        {
                            return  ;
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //ignore 
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code run like

```
  _proxies.ForEach(certainaction, timeOut);
```

Comment: I think what you're actually trying to do is a parallel foreach loop https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

Comment: @AnthonyRussell no here I need only the fastest process to be done , and not all

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for. What output? Do you mean instead of `void` you want it to return something? If so, what? Additionally, I can't see how this is "faster". If anything, it'll be significantly slower than just executing your tasks on the same thread. If you're just spawning new threads so that you can break out of the loop if one task fails, consider using a single thread with stopwatch instead. It's much faster, far easier to debug and will do what you wan. If you really want them to run in parallel, this is not the way.

Comment: @kha this IEnnumerable of processes, it's like load balancing , if the first not responded the second should , I want to return the output of action

Comment: `this will enhance the performance and code readability`. No, it definitely won't :) You create plenty of problems with this code: redundant logging, exception swallowing, unreadable code with not clear intentions, code is being executed not in parallel due to `.Wait()` etc.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev any  suggestion then to achieve this

Comment: @Ali The question is **what is your initial struggle and what are you trying to achieve?**

Comment: How do you pass your `mxAccessProxy` to `action`?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I have a list of objects refer to processes and I want to check one by one if called the input function return the result

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev this is extention method   _proxies.ForEach(PingOfDeath, timeOut);

Comment: Doesn't `Task.WaitAny()` or `Task.WhenAny()` do the job?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto No because other running tasks will complete, so instead of writing once , u will n times

Comment: @Ali https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-remaining-async-tasks-after-one-is-complete

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto Hmm this will put a risk of two tasks end on same time, any idea how return Action result please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this will enhance the performance and code readability

No, it definitely won't :) Moreover, you bring some more problems with this code like redundant locking or exception swallowing, but don't actually execute code in parallel.

It seems like you want to get the fastest possible call for your `Action` using some sort of proxy objects. You need to run `Tasks` asynchronously, not consequently with `.Wait()`.

Something like this could be helpful for you:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static TReturn ParallelSelectReturnFastest<TPoolObject, TReturn>(this TPoolObject[] pool,
        Func<TPoolObject, CancellationToken, TReturn> func, 
        int? timeout = null)
    {
        var ctx = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // for every object in pool schedule a task
        Task<TReturn>[] tasks = pool
            .Select(poolObject =>
            {
                ctx.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(poolObject, ctx.Token), ctx.Token);
            })
            .ToArray();

       // not sure if Cast is actually needed, 
       // just to get rid of co-variant array conversion
       int firstCompletedIndex = timeout.HasValue
            ? Task.WaitAny(tasks.Cast<Task>().ToArray(), timeout.Value, ctx.Token)
            : Task.WaitAny(tasks.Cast<Task>().ToArray(), ctx.Token);

        // we need to cancel token to avoid unnecessary work to be done
        ctx.Cancel();

        if (firstCompletedIndex == -1) // no objects in pool managed to complete action in time
            throw new NotImplementedException(); // custom exception goes here

        return tasks[firstCompletedIndex].Result;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use this extension method to call a specific action on any pool of objects and get the first executed result:

```
var pool = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var result = pool.ParallelSelectReturnFastest((x, token) => { 
    Thread.Sleep(x * 200); 
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    Console.WriteLine("calculate");
    return x * x; 
}, 100);    
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

It outputs:

> calculate
>   1

Because the first task will complete work in 200ms, return it, and all other tasks will be cancelled through cancellation token.

In your case it will be something like:

```
var actionResponse = proxiesList.ParallelSelectReturnFastest((proxy, token) => {
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    return proxy.SomeAction();        
});
```

Some things to mention:

- Make sure that your actions are safe. You can't rely on how many of these will actually come to the actual execution of your action. If this action is `CreateItem`, then you can end up with many items to be created through different proxies
- It cannot guarantee that you will run all of these actions in parallel, because it is up to TPL to chose the optimal number of running tasks
- I have implemented in old-fashioned TPL way, because your original question contained it. If possible, you need to switch to async/await - in this case your `Func` will return tasks and you need to use `await Task.WhenAny(tasks)` instead of `Task.WaitAny()`